# How to host a "local" webpage without needing to make it a real webpage?

Tags: css, local, html

I've tried finding an answer on the web and google for this but it just tells me how to HOST a webpage and I don't want anyone else to get to this webpage. I want to be able to write my HTML and CSS and see it before having it put anywhere.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You can literally just open the HTML file in your browser

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "Host" a webpage to view it (unless you are using server side code).

Just save your file with the .html extension and then open it with your web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WAMP or XAMPP for running a local testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just HTML and CSS you don't have to host it. Just open the *.html file in the browser from your local storage with relative paths to your CSS/images.

If you want to use PHP for example (server side code) you can install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), a free and open source apache distribution as popular develop environment.